# DataTableRepository in Spring data Elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-elasticsearch

Currently, we are using spring data JPA with MySql database with [DataTabaleRepository](https://github.com/darrachequesne/spring-data-jpa-datatables) which works well with JPA. Now we are moving our data to Spring data elasticserch but [DataTabaleRepository](https://github.com/darrachequesne/spring-data-jpa-datatables) is not working with that. Is there any alternative for that or how can I implement a custom repository for that?

Comment: Which part is exactly not working?

Comment: I want to customize the response in the same way in https://github.com/darrachequesne/spring-data-jpa-datatables ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[spring-data-jpa-datatables](https://github.com/darrachequesne/spring-data-jpa-datatables) does not implement support for ElasticsearchRepository, as you say and use the Specification API which is not implemented by Spring Data for Elasticsearch, so extending it would take some work.

What you need to do is create your own [ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/repository/support/ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.java) (ie. ElasticsearchDataTablesRepositoryFactoryBean) and your own implementation of [AbstractElasticsearchRepository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/repository/support/AbstractElasticsearchRepository.java) that implements the specifics of spring-data-jpa-datatables just like [DataTablesRepositoryImpl](https://github.com/darrachequesne/spring-data-jpa-datatables/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/datatables/repository/DataTablesRepositoryImpl.java). You should also define your own [DataTablesRepository](https://github.com/darrachequesne/spring-data-jpa-datatables/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/datatables/repository/DataTablesRepository.java) (ElasticsearchDataTablesRepository that extends ElasticsearchRepository) with the same methods.

The org.springframework.data.jpa.datatables.mapping classes can be reused, but you'll have to recreate the logic found in [SpecificationFactory](https://github.com/darrachequesne/spring-data-jpa-datatables/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/datatables/repository/SpecificationFactory.java)  for elasticsearch using [QueryBuilders](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/1.3/query-dsl-queries.html), which will be the most time consuming part I imagine.

When you're done, you can use the @EnableElasticsearchRepositories just like described by spring-data-jpa-datatables ie.:

```
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = ElasticsearchDataTablesRepositoryFactoryBean.class))
```

And extend your repositories with your ElasticsearchDataTablesRepository interface and you're good to go.

For reference you should look at [SpecificationFactory](https://github.com/darrachequesne/spring-data-jpa-datatables/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/datatables/repository/SpecificationFactory.java) and [AbstractElasticsearchRepository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/repository/support/AbstractElasticsearchRepository.java) (the search method) and get familiar with Elasticsearch [QueryBuilders](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/1.3/query-dsl-queries.html).